# Facebook's React on Android

Tags: android, facebook, reactjs

I tried to run some examples from http://facebook.github.io/react/docs in Android browser and they don't work - got empty pages. All pages are served from Django dev web server that is run locally and work fine except those with React. Exact same links work fine on the laptop. From their docs "If you'd like to use React on a touch device (i.e. a phone or tablet), simply call `React.initializeTouchEvents(true);` to turn them on." I assume there should be no problems with running on mobile devices. Are there some gotchas that I'm missing here? 
The source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="/static/phs/js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/phs/js/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <div id="example1"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        /** @jsx React.DOM */
        React.initializeTouchEvents(true);
        var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            return (
              <p>
                Hello, <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" />!
                It is {this.props.date.toTimeString()}
              </p>
            );
          }
        });

        setInterval(function() {
          React.renderComponent(
            <HelloWorld date={new Date()} />,
            document.getElementById('example')
          );
        }, 1000);

        var LikeButton = React.createClass({
          getInitialState: function() {
            return {liked: false};
          },
          handleClick: function(event) {
            this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});
          },
          render: function() {
            var text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'unlike';
            return (
              <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
                You {text} this. Click to toggle.
              </p>
            );
          }
        });

        React.renderComponent(
          <LikeButton />,
          document.getElementById('example1')
        );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Included valid code as requested.

Comment: The answer turned out to be simple - neither Dolphin nor outdated built in Android(2.3.5) browser support this new technology. Fixed by installing latest Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 1):

React didn't work for me on Android's 2.3.5 built-in browser and Dolphin Browser 10.1.2. Fixed by installing latest Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out it is possible to get React to work on Android Browser, at least on Android Browser 4 (I do not have earlier versions handy). The trick is that you have to manually add the polyfills on which React depends, specifically [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) and [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv).

More details on Facebook's stance as to why these are not included with React by default can be found [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#browser-support-and-polyfills). the short version is:

1. It's easier and better to write javascript libs to the spec;
2. If libraries include their own versions of the polyfills, and you use many libraries, you will send the same code multiple times.